# Access multiple elements and assign to each selected element a different value

Tags: matlab, indexing, variable-assignment, sparse-matrix

I need to know if there is any efficient way of doing the following in MATLAB.

I have several big sparse matrices, the size of each one is roughly 9000000x9000000.

I need to access multiple element of such matrix and assign to each selected element a different value stored in another array. I'll give an example:

What I have:

- SPARSE MATRIX of size 9000000x9000000
- Matrix with the list of indexes and values I want to access, this is a matrix like this:

  ```
  [row1, col1, value1;
   row2, col2, value2;
   ...
   rowN, colN, valueN]
  ```

Where `N` is the length of such matrix.

What I need:

Assign to the SPARSE MATRIX the corresponding value to the corresponding index, this is:

```
SPARSE_MATRIX(row1, col1) = value1
SPARSE_MATRIX(row2, col2) = value2
...
SPARSE_MATRIX(rowN, colN) = valueN
```

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

Thank you to both for answering, I think I did not explain myself well, I'll try again.

I already have a large SPARSE MATRIX of about 9000000 rows x 9000000 columns, it is a SPARSE MATRIX filled with zeros.

Then I have another array or matrix, let's call it `M` with `N` number of rows, where `N` could take values from 0 to 9000000; and 3 columns. The first two columns are used to index an element of my SPARSE MATRIX, and the third column stores the value I want to transfer to the SPARSE MATRIX, this is, given a random row of `M`, `i`:

`SPARSE_MATRIX(M(i, 1), M(i, 2)) = M(i, 3)`

The idea is to do that for all the rows, I have tried it with common indexing:

`SPARSE_MATRIX(M(:, 1), M(:, 2)) = M(:, 3)`

Now I would like to do this assignation for all the rows in `M` as fast as possible, because if I use a loop or common indexing it takes ages (I am using a 7th Gen i7 processor with 16 GB of RAM). And I also need to keep the zeros in the SPARSE_MATRIX.

- EDIT 2: SOLVED! Thank you Metahominid, I was not thinking through, but yes the sparse function does solve my problem, I just think my brain circuits were shortcircuited yesterday and was unable to see through it hahaha. Thank you to both anyway!

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a sparse matrix like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).

```
A = sparse(i,j,v)
```

> S = sparse(i,j,v) generates a sparse matrix S from the triplets i, j,
>   and v such that S(i(k),j(k)) = v(k). The max(i)-by-max(j) output
>   matrix has space allotted for length(v) nonzero elements. sparse adds
>   together elements in v that have duplicate subscripts in i and j.

So you can simply construct the row vector, column vector and value vector.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering in part because I cannot comment.  You question seems a little confusing to me. The sparse() function in MATLAB does just this.

You can enter your arrays of indices and values directly into the interface, or declare a sparse matrix of zeros and set each individually.

Given your data format make three vectors, ROWS = [row1; ...; rown], COLS = [col1; ...; coln], and DATA = [val1; ... valn].  I am assuming that your size is the overall size of the full matrix and not the sparse portion.

Then

A = sparse(ROWS, COLS, DATA) will do just what you want.  You can even specify the original matrix size.

A = sparse(ROWS, COLS, DATA, 90...., 90....).